# How to set zero line not on zero in horizontal bar chart?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

In my project i need to set the zero line not on zero. I use the horizontal bar chart.

I've tried find in docs some information about this but find nothing.

Ideally me need type in input field the number where me need to set zero line like on this screenshot

[image: sreen]

But at now i just try to figure out how to set zero line not on zero )

Comment: Check "Updating Axis Defaults" in the documentation: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/

Comment: @neophytte Firstly, I did not find "scaleService" and therefore "updateScaleDefaults" too, and such a construction "Chart.scaleService.updateScaleDefaults" only shows an error and nothing else. And as far as I understand, this is the same as in the initial config in the "options" just writing "ticks: {min: 50}" and it will still not be what I need, unfortunately.